# How to extract subset of object properties as object in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I in ES6 , elegantly and with simple syntax, create a new object from the existing object which has only subset of its properties ?

I currently use object destructuring but I don't like the duplicity here.

```
  const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}
  // Create copy which has only a, b and c
  const {a, b, c} = obj
  const newObj = {a, b, c}
```

Is there a syntax in which I would need to specify the names of properties only once ?

Comment: Have a look at this: `object.asssign` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Can you expand on this a little - it's a bit vague `create a new object from the existing object which has only subset of its properties` - which subset? You have an example?

Comment: Can't you just filter object by key?